# How to convert a soup to a Dataframe

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

I am new to the beautiful soup. I am working to scrape some excel files from a source.
URL to source: https://droughtmonitor.unl.edu/DmData/GISData.aspx/?mode=table&aoi=county&date=
Original Data source: https://droughtmonitor.unl.edu/DmData/GISData.aspx/

My main objective is to scrape the data from this URL and convert the same into a data frame including all the files in the original data source URL and also if some new files added could be downloaded automatically and added to the source.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

url2 = 'https://droughtmonitor.unl.edu/DmData/GISData.aspx/?mode=table&aoi=county&date=2022-06-21'
r2 = requests.get(url2)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r2.text,'html.parser')
raw_data = [data.text for data in soup]
```

The above code gives me an output:-

```
["MapDate,FIPS,County,State,Nothing,D0,D1,D2,D3,D4,ValidStart,ValidEnd\r\n20220621,01001,Autauga County,AL,100.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,2022-06-21,2022-06-27\r\n20220621,01003,Baldwin County,AL,81.22,18.78,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,2022-06-21,2022-06-27\r\n20220621,01005,Barbour County,AL,100.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,2022-06-21,2022-06-27\r\n20220621,01007,Bibb County,AL,100.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,2022-06-21,2022-06-27\r\n20220621,01009,Blount County,AL,100.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,2022-06-21,2022-06-27\r\n20220621,01011,Bullock County,AL,100.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,2022-06-21,2022-06-27\r\n20220621,01013,Butler County,AL,100.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,2022-06-21,2022-06-27\r\n20220621,01015,Calhoun County,AL,100.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,2022-06-21,2022-06-27\r\n20220621,01017,Chambers County,AL,100.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,2022-06-21,2022-06-27\r\n20220621,01019,Cherokee County,AL,69.27,30.73,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,2022-06-21,2022-06-27\r\n20220621,01021,Chilton County,AL,100.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,2022-06-21,2022-06-27\r\n
```

I want to have the inital 12 values: MapDate,FIPS,County,State,Nothing,D0,D1,D2,D3,D4,ValidStart,ValidEnd
to be my column name and rest to the values associated with the same.

Also, the original data source URL has values from the year 2000 to 2022. I need all the data in the same format and in a single CSV.

Also, I need to have the code in such a manner that it will automatically extract any new data added to the source.

Can someone guide me on this.

Comment: if HTML displays data as `<table>` then you can use `all_tables = pandas.read_html(r2.text)`  and later `df = all_tables[index]`. For more complex structure you have to write all code to search elements in code.

Comment: it seems it sends file csv - so you could use directly `df = pd.read_csv( r2.text )` . OR use module `csv` for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sends file `csv` so you don't need `BeautifulSoup`

You can use `io` with `pandas.read_csv()`

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import io

url = 'https://droughtmonitor.unl.edu/DmData/GISData.aspx/?mode=table&aoi=county&date=2022-06-21'

response = requests.get(url)

fh = io.StringIO(response.text)  # create file in memory
df = pd.read_csv(fh)

print(df)
```

or you can use `io` with module `csv`

```
import requests
import csv
import io

url = 'https://droughtmonitor.unl.edu/DmData/GISData.aspx/?mode=table&aoi=county&date=2022-06-21'

response = requests.get(url)

fh = io.StringIO(response.text)  # create file in memory
data = list(csv.reader(fh))

print(data)
```

---

**EDIT:**

You can even use `url` directly with `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://droughtmonitor.unl.edu/DmData/GISData.aspx/?mode=table&aoi=county&date=2022-06-21'

df = pd.read_csv(url)

print(df)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Now you need only list with dates and run `for`-loop to read all csv and keep on list. And later you can use `pandas.concat()` to convert this list to single `DataFrame`.

Pandas doc: [Merge, join, concatenate and compare](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html)

Minimal working example:

```
import pandas as pd

# --- before loop ---

all_dates = ["2022-06-21", "2022-06-14", "2022-06-07"]
all_dfs = []

# url without `2022-06-21` at the end
url = 'https://droughtmonitor.unl.edu/DmData/GISData.aspx/?mode=table&aoi=county&date='

# --- loop ---

for date in all_dates:
    print('date:', date)
    df = pd.read_csv( url + date )
    all_dfs.append( df )

# --- after loop --- 

full_df = pd.concat(all_dfs)
print(full_df)
```

To get list of dates you could scrape them from webpage but it may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) instead of  `beautifulsoup`because page uses JavaScript to add dates on page.

Or you should use `DevTools` (tab: `Network`, filter: `XHR`) to see what url is used by JavaScript to get dates and use `requests` to get them.

```
import requests

# without header `Content-Type` it sends `HTML` instead of `JSON`
headers = {
#    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0',
#    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
#    'Referer': 'https://droughtmonitor.unl.edu/DmData/GISData.aspx/',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
}

url = 'https://droughtmonitor.unl.edu/DmData/GISData.aspx/ReturnDMWeeks'

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
#print(response.text)

data = response.json()

all_dates = data['d']
all_dates = [f"{d[:4]}-{d[4:6]}-{d[6:]}" for d in all_dates]

print(all_dates)
```

Result

```
['2022-06-21', '2022-06-14', '2022-06-07', ..., '2000-01-18', '2000-01-11', '2000-01-04']
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is giving me 1 file but I have a range of dates that I need to pass in the URL and scrape the data of all the files. I tried but I am only getting the data for the last date passed. Is there a way so that we can pass various dates and the data keeps on adding to this file?

Comment: standar method - create list with dates and use `for`-loop to run the same code but with different date. - `for date in ["2022-06-21", "2022-06-14", "2022-06-07"]: url = "...&date=" + date ...rest...`. And only you have to check how to use functions `merge(()/join()/conatenate()` in `pandas`. See pandas doc: [Merge, join, concatenate and compare](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html)

Comment: I added code which use loop to get all csv, and code which get all dates from server.